# what does "lst := List[int]{}" mean in Go

Tags: go

Here is the part of Go code I am reading:

```
func main() {
    var m = map[int]string{1: "2", 2: "4", 4: "8"}

    fmt.Println("keys m:", MapKeys(m))

    _ = MapKeys[int, string](m)

    **lst := List[int]{}**
    lst.Push(10)
    lst.Push(13)
    lst.Push(23)
    fmt.Println("list:", lst.GetAll())
}
```

Anyone can explain what is code below defined ?

```
lst := List[int]{}
```

Comment: Where is this `List` type from? It's not the std one, is it?

Comment: I see, it's from Go By Example, right? The `List` type takes a [generic type parameter](https://go.dev/blog/intro-generics). That tells the list what kind of element it's gonna hold. When you initialize the list here with `List[int]{}`, you're telling Go that this list will take elements of type `int`. If you instead did `List[float]{}`, you wouldn't be able to push those `int`s because the list expects only `float`s.

Comment: thank you so much , it is coding sample from 'Go By Example' I missed out the part you point out : List definition part